# Call UIKit function from SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have a Storyboard UIKit function getAcctBalance(). In my UIKit file I display a  UIHostingController to load a UIKit view. In the UIKit view I want to call my function getAcctBalance().

UIKit:

```
import UIKit
import SWXMLHash

struct UserDashboard: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userModel: UserDashboardModel

    Button(action: {
       UserDashboardHostVC.getAcctBalance() //This function call is not working
    }){
       Text("Load Balance")
    }

    Text(userModel.totalBalance) //by default it is 0.0 and when button is pressed it should return 599
}
```

UIKit:

```
import UIKit

class UserDashboardModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var totalBalance     = 0.0
}

class UserDashboardHostVC: UIViewController {
    
    var userModel = UserDashboardModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: UserDashboard(userModel: self.userModel))
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChild(controller)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)

    }
    func getAcctBalance {
        userModel.totalBalance = 599
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806

Comment: This seems a little over my head, I don't see a UIHostingController being used on this post.

Comment: That is why I didn't post it as a duplicate but it is very similar. In the link you start with SwiftUI and then a `UIViewController` so you need a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. You are starting at the `UIViewController` and then going to SwiftUI via the hosting controller. But the communication is the same. The `UserDashboardModel` needs to hold a reference to `UserDashboardHostVC` so the `Button` can call the method in `UserDashboardModel` that will then call the method in `UserDashboardHostVC`, like a delegate of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample

```
class UserDashboardModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var totalBalance     = 0.0
    internal var uIViewController: UserDashboardHostVC? = nil
    
    func getAcctBalance(){
        if uIViewController != nil{
            uIViewController!.getAcctBalance()
        }else{
            print("view controller is not connected")
        }
    }
}
struct UserDashboard: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userModel: UserDashboardModel
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                userModel.getAcctBalance() //Call shared model
            }){
                Text("Load Balance")
            }
            
            Text(userModel.totalBalance.description) //Now it will change
        }.frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
    }
}
class UserDashboardHostVC: UIViewController {
    
    var userModel = UserDashboardModel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Crucial connection
        userModel.uIViewController = self
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: UserDashboard(userModel: self.userModel))
        
        self.addChild(controller)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //Update constraints per use case
        controller.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        controller.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
        
    }
    func getAcctBalance() {
        userModel.totalBalance = 599
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm falling in the else "view controller is not connected"

Comment: If I take away the else and run uIViewController!.getAcctBalance() I get "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Look at what I wrote in the viewDidLoad method. The line after the super call. You are missing that line of code. You should always check for nil before forcing

Comment: @SebastienDesemberg did you get it working?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I missed the crucial connect. It works well. I like this method over using UIViewControllerRepresentable, I think it is smarter code. Thank you.