# Passing .USDZ Data from SwiftUI to UIKit

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

This code performs as operated if running in just SwiftUI. I am trying to get it wrapped and loading properly in UIKit. When it runs it is a blank screen. I have looked at similar problems, and some recommended environment object. I am have tried implementing that with no luck - here is where I at with it. The result should be the USDZ file loading at the top.

Here is the ModalLoader

```
 struct ModalLoader: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Popup()
        
        
    }
}

//Popup View...



struct Popup : View{
    //Sample Data
    
    @State var models = [
            ModelData(id: 0, name: "breadBun", modelName: "breadBun.usdz", details: "proprir jrjriri riririri oriorororo riirir orororor iiririri."),
            ModelData(id: 0, name: "Bread", modelName: "Bread.usdz", details: "proprir jrjriri riririri oriorororo riirir orororor iiririri."),
            ModelData(id: 0, name: "bun", modelName: "bun.usdz", details: "proprir jrjriri riririri oriorororo riirir orororor iiririri."),
            ModelData(id: 0, name: "cake", modelName: "cake.usdz", details: "proprir jrjriri riririri oriorororo riirir orororor iiririri."),
    
    ]
    
    @State var index = 0
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
         
            //Going to use SceneKit Scene View
            
            //default is first object ie: breadBun
            
            //Scene View has a default camera view...
            //if custom means is needed add there...
            
            SceneView(scene: SCNScene(named: models[index].modelName), options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting, .allowsCameraControl])
            
            //for user actions...
            // setting custom frames..
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
        }
    }
}

//Data Model
struct ModelData : Identifiable {
    var id : Int
    var name : String
    var modelName : String
    var details : String
      
}
```

And here is the host controller.

```
class ModalHostController: UIViewController{
    
        
    let modalView = UIHostingController(rootView: ModalLoader())
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addChild(modalView)
        view.addSubview(modalView.view)
        setupConstraints()
    }
                                        

    fileprivate func setupConstraints() {
        modalView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        modalView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        modalView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        modalView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        modalView.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a State variable share a ViewModel that is the source of truth. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942854/how-to-pass-textfield-value-to-view-controller-through-button-click-in-swift-ui/69945806#69945806

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435695/call-uikit-function-from-swiftui/70437340#70437340

Comment: I tried replicating the 2nd URL you have listed -- with the function in the HostController file. It is a function, GetModel(), which will pull the Array of Models. The issue though, is I need to get X element of model, so the method for a shared ViewModel is not working at the moment