# How to update a SwiftUI view when its array changes (Delete or Add to array)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a wallet view that is called via tab bar controller.  The wallet items are stored in a array called **walletItems**.  Let's say there are two items in the array when I initially go into wallet.  So I can swipe back and forth between the two items.  Then I decide to delete or add another item to my walletItems array.  When I go back into the view the original two items are still in the wallet.  I want the view to show what's CURRENTLY in the walletItems array.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class WalletSwipeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBSegueAction func embedSwiftUIView(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
        return UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: WalletView())
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //collectionView.backgroundColor = .green
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       print("IN WALLET WILL LOAD")
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        //universal.loadWallet()
    }

}


struct WalletView: View {
    
   // @State var wic = walletItemsChanged
   
    //let universal = Universal()
    init() {
        //@ObservedObject var wIO : WalletItemsObservable
        UIPageControl.appearance().currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .green
        UIPageControl.appearance().pageIndicatorTintColor = .red   //.withAlphaComponent(1.5)
        //coupText = walletItems[0].busID!
    }
    //@ObservedObject var wIO : WalletItemsObservable
    //@ObservedObject var wIO : WalletItemsObservable
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TabView{
            
                ForEach(**walletItems**) {wall in
                //ForEach(wIO.wI) { wall in
                    let temp = wall.busID! + "-" + String(wall.dealNum)
            
                    VStack{
                        
                        Text(wall.busID!)
                            .padding(20)
                        Image(uiImage: wallImages[temp]!)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 300.0, height: 400.0)
                            
                            
                    }
                }
            }
            //.background(Color.red)
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .interactive))
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .padding(10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435695/call-uikit-function-from-swiftui/70437340#70437340

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I looked at your example provided above in your comment.  Will your example work when the observed object(in my case an array) is changed in a different screen?  I see how this works if the array is changed in the screen.   However, none of my code I implemented is getting hit in debug.  Granted, I may have implemented this completely wrong.  Thanks again

Comment: An Array can't be an ObservableObject you can have an Array of ObservableObject but the array itself can't be. As far as your question yes it can be updated from anywhere but you need to make sure that the same instance is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically update your TabView based on changes in the walletItems array, you should use an ObservableObject to represent your data. Create an ObservableObject class (e.g., `WalletItemsObservable`) with a published property for the walletItems array. In your WalletView, use @ObservedObject to observe changes in the WalletItemsObservable. This way, when you add or remove items from the walletItems array, SwiftUI will automatically update the TabView to reflect the changes.

Comment: I think I'm close I added this

Comment: lorem ipsum I added this class WalletItemsObservable : ObservableObject 
{@Published var wI = walletItemsand } then in WalletView added @ObservedObject var wIO: WalletItemsObservable

Comment: Thank you so much!  It took some debugging but you definitely got me close enough to make this solution work with my code