# How to disable a SwiftUI button from UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, togglebutton

I have the following SwiftUI custom Toggle button:

```
struct TwoStateButton: View {
    @State var isSelected: Bool
    @State var isDisabled: Bool

    var onTap: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $isSelected) {
            Image("buttonImage")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 4, bottom: 4, trailing: 4))
                .background(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.clear)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 50)
                        .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                )
        }
        .disabled(isDisabled)
        .toggleStyle(.button)
        .onChange(of: isSelected) { value in
            if let onTap {
                onTap(value)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isEnabled) { value in
            print("\(isEnabled)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to disable the button, this code is being called from UIKit in this way:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    private lazy var twoStateButton: TwoStateButton = {
        return TwoStateButton(isSelected: false, isDisabled: false)
    }()

    private lazy var toggleButton: UIView = {
        return UIHostingController(rootView: twoStateView).view
    }()

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    
        self.addSubview(toggleButton)
    }

    func updateView() {
        twoStateButton.isDisabled.toggle()

        print("twoStateButton.isDisabled=\(twoStateButton.isDisabled)"
    }
}
```

Every time the `updateView` is being called, the print below shows as:

```
twoStateButton.isDisabled=false
```

And the one inside `.onChange(of: isSelected)` never gets executed

How could I effectively disable the SwiftUI Toggle button?

Comment: You would need an ObservableObject with a Bool for toggling. SwiftUI views are value types and you can’t access their properties from a parent, especially State

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ObservableObject, especially with how to use it inside UIKit, could it be possible to show an example of it @loremipsum?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435695/call-uikit-function-from-swiftui/70437340#70437340